# nginx kibana reverse proxy problem with location as /kibana

Tags: nginx, kibana

I am doing nginx reverse proxy+ kibana , have problem with
location as /kibana, if i am suing location as / , it will work
Any suggestion or feedback ? thanks in advance

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.rsa;
    location  /kibana/ {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd ;
        
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:5601;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

problem i got is as below when i browse https://<nginx_server>/kibana

```
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution need to change kibana config, then it will work

```
server.basePath: "/kibana"
server.rewriteBasePath: true
```